# Symfony2: How to enable autocompletion for annotations in PHPStorm?

Tags: symfony, phpstorm

Following this simple code:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


class TestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param $value
     * @return Response
     */
    public function indexAction($value)
    {
        return new Response('Hello:' . $value);
    }
}
```

Is any possibility to have code completion when I would like to add @Route in phpDoc? When I type @Route it should show code completion and automatic add "use" statement? I watched a symfony tutorial (I'm beginner) and in this video PHPStrom showed code completion and automatic added "use" statement... I installed symfony plugin and other things and code completions works.

Comment: You need the PHP Annotations plugin..

Comment: Thanks a lot! You made my day ;)

Answer (score 10):

As correctly stated by Patrik Karisch in the question's comments:

You need the to install the [PHP Annotations Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7320) to enable:

- autocompletion
- automatic addition of `use`-statements

... and other helpers for annotations in PHPStorm.

Installation:

- Go To **Preferences > Plugins -> Browse Repositories**
- Enter *"Annotation"* into the Search box
- Locate the **PHP Annotations** Plugin in the Result List
- Click **Install**
- Restart PHPStorm to enable the plugin

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a high enough reputation to comment, so I'll add this as an additonal answer. If you are following some sort of guide or video tutorial, and are unable to get the @Assert to autocomplete, this is because Validator has not been imported into the file you're editing.

add this to your use statements:
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

The course I was following didn't mention this, and I ended up finding it on some random website.

For some reason php storm doesn't give you the option to import it once you've typed it out, like it usually does.